# Cannot open Mail.app Preferences in OS X 10.7.5

Tags: mail.app, performance, preferences

I get the pinwheel of death when I try to open Mail Preferences. I'm using OS X 10.7.5 and Mail v5.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset Mail's settings by running the following one-liner in Terminal:

```
killall Mail &> /dev/null; mv ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist ~/Desktop && open -a Mail
```

https://georgegarside.com/o/se/reset-osx-mail.html